# Laravel method to add a value within a deeply nested array using "dot" notation

Tags: arrays, laravel

`Arr::add` doesn't work with `dot` notation. `Arr::set` will create a new element only if it does not exist, otherwise, it will overwrite the existing one. There is `data_set`, it works similar to `Arr::set`, but it accepts the `overwrite` flag which does not do what I need (if it's set to false instead of adding a new item, it will just skip setting new value).

My code:

```
   $array = [['name' => 'Test', 'link' => 'test_link'], ['name' => 'Test1', 'link' => 'test1_link']];

   $result = [];
   $position = 1;
   foreach($array as $element) {
      Arr::set($result, 'itemListElement.type', 'ListItem');  
      Arr::set($result, 'itemListElement.position', $position);  
      Arr::set($result, 'itemListElement.item.name', $element['name']);  
      Arr::set($result, 'itemListElement.item.link', $element['link']);  
      $position++;
   }
```

And I would like to have multiple `list elements` within the `itemListElement` parent, instead of having one `list element` which is being overwritten all the time.

Here is what it should look like:

```
[
    "itemListElement" => [
        [
            "type" => "ListItem",
            "position" => 1,
            "item" => [
                "name" => "Test",
                "url" => "test_url",
            ]
        ],
        [
            "type" => "ListItem",
            "position" => 1,
            "item" => [
                "name" => "Test1",
                "url" => "test1_url",
            ]
        ],
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
 $array = [['name' => 'Test', 'link' => 'test_link'], ['name' => 'Test1', 'link' => 'test1_link']];

   $result = [];
   foreach($array as $key=>$element) {
      Arr::set($result["itemListElement"][$key], 'type', 'ListItem');  
      Arr::set($result["itemListElement"][$key], 'position', $key + 1);  
      Arr::set($result["itemListElement"][$key], 'item.name', $element['name']);  
      Arr::set($result["itemListElement"][$key], 'item.link', $element['link']);  
   }

$result;
```